# NameError: name 'BertModel' is not defined, error while importing Bert extractive summarizer

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I have freshly installed Anaconda module and installed Bert extractive summarizer package. The following error is being encountered by me while importing the module:

```
from transformers import *
from summarizer import Summarizer
```

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\summarizer\model_processors.py in <module>
----> 1 from summarizer.bert_parent import BertParent
      2 from summarizer.cluster_features import ClusterFeatures
      3 from summarizer.sentence_handler import SentenceHandler
      4 from typing import List
      5 from abc import abstractmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\summarizer\bert_parent.py in <module>
      9 
     10 
---> 11 class BertParent(object):
     12 
     13     """

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\summarizer\bert_parent.py in BertParent()
     16 
     17     MODELS = {
---> 18         'bert-base-uncased': (BertModel, BertTokenizer),
     19         'bert-large-uncased': (BertModel, BertTokenizer),
     20         'xlnet-base-cased': (XLNetModel, XLNetTokenizer),

NameError: name 'BertModel' is not defined
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python are you using. I face a similar error which i used python 3.5.x. This error got resolved once i uninstalled python3.5 and installed python 3.6

```
conda install python=3.6
```

Run this command and then restart your notebook. It will work

Comment: The issue is with Spacy and it has been resolved as soon as i have reinstalled spacy.

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the then newest version of spacy.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of spacy and Bert-extractive summarizer worked for you? I tried a few but I still get the same error.

Comment: @GenerousJoker Refer this notebook https://github.com/practical-nlp/practical-nlp/blob/master/Ch7/03_TextSummarization.ipynb